# Фильтр подбора товаров и вывода из бд

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql

Есть форма фильтра, в этой форме 4 select(выбора категории товара) и кнопка подобрать товар.Нужно сделать так чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку выводились товары из БД которые пользователь выбрал путем подбора в select.Пример https://auto.drom.ru/toyota/?go_search=2 ,только там категорий больше у меня их 4. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ага, а от нас чего хотите?

Comment: Разумеется совет,как это лучше реализовать, желательно с примером кода

Comment: Проблема в том, что Вы не можете передать в sql-запрос параметры из полей ввода формы?

Comment: Вернее сказать не знаю как это сделать...Смысл в том что надо чтобы вывелись товары из бд по этому запросу.